# Why can't 'org-clock-goto' find most recently clocked task in a fresh session?

Tags: org-mode, org-clock

If I open emacs and do a <kbd>C-c C-x C-k</kbd> I get the message, `No active or recent clock task`. In such a case, where I have not yet clocked a task since I started emacs, can I instead get `org-clock-goto` to find the most recently clocked task from the files in my agenda list?

Comment: What's your org-mode configuration, you might have not save org-clock session info. There is a command to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is code to always save clock session info to file.

```
;;; To save the clock history across Emacs sessions, use
(if (file-exists-p org-clock-persist-file)
    ;; (setq org-clock-persist 'history)
    (org-clock-persistence-insinuate)
  (shell-command (concat "touch " org-clock-persist-file)))
```

Comment: I am able to evaluate this once org-mode has been fully loaded, but if I put it in my `init.el` file, emacs complains that `org-clock-persist-file` doesn't exist. I tried a simple hook but that didn't fix the problem.

Comment: @BrianZ You need to load `org-timer` and `org-clock`.